# Positioning an enclosed div

Tags: html, css

How can one get a left floating element **with** a top position. For instance:

```
.......................
.......................
.......................
menu 1  ...............
menu 2  ...............
menu 3  ...............
.......................
.......................
```

I've used dots instead of normal text to make it clearer. Note that the text (dots) flows around the enclosed div (menu).

Here's a starting HTML

```
<div id="section">
    <div id="nav">
      <ul><li>menu 1</li><li>menu 2</li><li>menu 3</li></ul>
    </div>
................................and so on...
</div>
```

CSS

```
div#section {
    width: 600px;
    float left;
}

div#nav {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    top: 180px; /* Doesn't work. See below */
}
```

The problem is that specifying a position (top:180px) doesn't work since the block is within a flow. Taking it out of the flow using position:relative puts the box at the correct position but it will then overlap the text of the enclosing div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This effect can be created using a spacer div:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Content -->
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

---

```
.spacer {
    width:1px;
    margin-right:-1px;
    height:2em;
    float:left;  
}

.nav {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    padding:1em 1em 1em 0; 
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7Q7Fy/

Comment: Yes, this works. I hate introducing non semantic elements in the HTML though. I'll wait to see if anyone has a better solution. And thanks for the jsfiddle.net link. Great site to share and test code.

Comment: I agree 100% in regard to the addition of non-semantic elements, but I've yet to find a better alternative for this situation. I don't believe the same can be accomplished with simple CSS rules or even pseudo elements, but I'd gladly accept a more semantic solution as well.

Comment: For reference, this code needs a slight fix for some versions of Internet Explorer (I've only tested on IE7 so far). The .spacer needs to have at least width:2px otherwise the height is simply ignored.

Comment: Clarification on my previous comment. Under IE7 (and possibly other versions of IE), the .spacer div needs to have at least 1px effective width. That is its width plus its margin-right must be at least 1px otherwise the height is simply ignored. The trick of cancelling the 1px width with a 1px negative margin doesn't work for IE unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried margin-top: 180px? Seems like it should work because I regularly use margin on floated elements to ensure some kind of gutter around its edge.

Comment: No, that doesn't work. See comments for the margin-top answer. I'm testing with Chrome btw, which is probably the most compliant browser out there.

Comment: Oh yeah, makes sense. The gutter I mentioned would fill the space above. Though, the "spirit" of CSS float is for things inline that you want to shove to one side or the other. This isn't really in line with that spirit, sometime one ought to work with the limitations of the medium they're working with, rather than fight with it.

Comment: Let me clarify. If you want to achieve the effect of a floated element surrounded all peninsula-like by body text on 3 sides, you could just move the element down in the markup about 1/3 way through the body text. It wouldn't be any exact number of pixels down, but it would be a integral number of lines down which is probably better anyway.

Comment: It's also more semantic that way too. Imagine a screen reader. Some text, some text, "oh interesting sidebar let's read that", ok more text.

Comment: Inlining the box inside the text makes sense for images or comments about a specific section of the text. That's not the case here. It's a menu. The graphics constrains also mean that I need to make it fit in a very constrained space (the width of the enclosing div). I also do not want the menu at the top left. The first paragraph or so of the text is more important. Oh, and the text is actually dynamic (Wordpress template).

Answer (score 1):

Use a positive `margin-top` value to shift the whole thing down:

```
div#nav {
    margin-top: 180px;
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: margin-top doesn't work here. It positions the enclosed div correctly but no text (dots) flows above it. The same for padding-top.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work as is if you cut the "nav" div out and paste it halfway through the text

```
<div id="section">
justo sit amet sem dignissim volutpat. Praesent non tellus erat. Pellentesque suscipit ipsum ut arcu pharetra viverra. Vivamus faucibus, libero eget tincidunt iaculis, mauris ligula suscipit ipsum, a tincidunt ipsum nisl non ipsum. Vivamus ullamcorper enim in lacus volutpat venenatis porta tellus tincidunt. Curabitur consectetur enim eget libero placerat vitae egestas 

<div id="nav">
      <ul><li>menu 1</li><li>menu 2</li><li>menu 3</li></ul>
</div>

justo sit amet sem dignissim volutpat. Praesent non tellus erat. Pellentesque suscipit ipsum ut arcu pharetra viverra. Vivamus faucibus, libero eget tincidunt iaculis, mauris ligula suscipit ipsum, a tincidunt ipsum nisl non ipsum. Vivamus ullamcorper enim in lacus volutpat venenatis porta tellus tincidunt. Curabitur consectetur enim eget libero placerat vitae egestas 
</div>
```

Comment: Sure, but that's not useful in practice. You'd need to readjust the position of the nav every time you edit the text. Moreover, you'd still have the problem of optimising on various devices (iPhone, tablets) unless you use CSS for those, but then you'd hit the problem I'm asking about. Anyway, @darkporter mentioned inlining already. See my reply to that.